# Images not shown/broken on android phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make some simple game with cubes, i made an 2 array's of images like show down, in my code im showing 'kockice' as starting images and later on button click in my view I'm replacing them with 'zkockice', with $timeout in between for one anim.gif (it looks like shuffling), all looks great in chrome, but, when i go ionic run android and simulate on my mobile phone(android) it shows broken images, so is there some resource problem or anaything else?

```
var kockice = new Array();
      kockice[0] = new Image();
      kockice[0].src = "/img/1.jpg";
      kockice[1] = new Image();
      kockice[1].src = "/img/2.jpg";
      kockice[2] = new Image();
      kockice[2].src = "/img/3.jpg";
      kockice[3] = new Image();
      kockice[3].src = "/img/4.jpg";
      kockice[4] = new Image();
      kockice[4].src = "/img/5.jpg";
      kockice[5] = new Image();
      kockice[5].src = "/img/6.jpg";

      var zkockice = new Array();
      zkockice[0] = new Image();
      zkockice[0].src = "/img/k1.jpg";
      zkockice[1] = new Image();
      zkockice[1].src = "/img/k2.jpg";
      zkockice[2] = new Image();
      zkockice[2].src = "/img/k3.jpg";
      zkockice[3] = new Image();
      zkockice[3].src = "/img/k4.jpg";
      zkockice[4] = new Image();
      zkockice[4].src = "/img/k5.jpg";
      zkockice[5] = new Image();
      zkockice[5].src = "/img/k6.jpg";

      var anim = "/img/anim.gif";

//here's the view, it shows starting images, but when on-click happens images get broken (in time when they have to change)
div class="row">
  <div class="col" id="k1"><img ng-src="img/1.jpg" ng-click="promjeni1()" id="sk1"></div>
  <div class="col" id="k2"><img ng-src="img/2.jpg" ng-click="promjeni2()" id="sk2"></div>
  <div class="col" id="k3"><img ng-src="img/3.jpg" ng-click="promjeni3()" id="sk3"></div>
  <div class="col" id="k4"><img ng-src="img/4.jpg" ng-click="promjeni4()" id="sk4"></div>
  <div class="col" id="k5"><img ng-src="img/5.jpg" ng-click="promjeni5()" id="sk5"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: In the original images you use the path `img/..`, while you use `/img/...` in the js values. Check if `img` is really located in your `/`.

Comment: Are the array images (k1, k2...) in a different folder to 1.jpg, 2.jpg...? Because it looks like the two sets of images are in different folder levels

Comment: all images are in same folder, i did  it, thx for answers, it was '/' that was making trouble as Geral said, i removed it from everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Just remove the `/` in front of the `.src`